# Find html Footer tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have on html file in that there is one footer tag like this
`<footer data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
   <h4 > My Web Site </h4>
 </footer>`

i want to hide this footer using javascript please help me out.

Comment: Please say what you've tried next time, perhaps including what you've searched for.

Comment: okay thank you for you suggestion next time i won't do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementsByTagName`.

```
document.querySelector('footer').style = 'display: none'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i got my solutions from this way `document.querySelector('footer').style.display = 'none'` i am trying to achieve this in android and it work for me this.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign this footer an id and then use the [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) to retrieve it and hide it:

```
document.getElementById('footer_id').style = 'display: none;';
```

As an alternative you could use the [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) function if you cannot modify the markup.

```
var footers = document.getElementsByTagName('footer');
footers[0].style = 'display: none;';
```

Obviously if you have more than one `<footer>` elements in your markup the `getElementsByTagName` function will return all of them and you will have to pick the right element from the array.

Comment: Wow, edit much? ;) Attempting to write a comment on the question, and in that time span, you've significantly changed your answer.

Comment: Significantly changed my answer? I wouldn't say so. I first answered the question and then provided a sample code for the two solutions I've initially proposed.